# How can a get Java to throw an exception when user enters something other than a double?

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a program that calculates the amount of paint needed to cover a wall based on the area of the wall. The height and width of the wall(doubles) are input by a user. I need the program to re-prompt the user if an invalid input is given (i.e. a string). I already have an exception if the user enters a non valid numeral(i.e. a negative) but I can't find a way to get the program to display my error message and prompt for input if a string or character are entered. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    double wallHeight = 0.0;
    double wallWidth = 0.0;
    double wallArea = 0.0;
    double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
    final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
    char userDone = 'n'; 

    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    while (userDone != 'q') {

        try {

    // Prompt user to input wall's height
            System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
            wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            if (wallHeight <= 0) {  //error message for 0 or neg height input
                throw new Exception ("Invalid height.");
            }

    // Prompt user to input wall's width
            System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
            wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
            if (wallWidth <= 0) {  //error message for 0 or neg width input
                throw new Exception ("Invalid width.");
            }

    // Calculate and output wall area
            wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
            System.out.println("Wall area: " + wallArea + " square feet");
    // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
            gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
            System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");
        }
        catch (Exception excpt) {
            System.out.println(excpt.getMessage());
        }


    // Prompt user to quit or continue
            System.out.println("Would you like to start a new calculation? \n(press any key to continue or 'q' to quit)");
            userDone = scnr.next().charAt(0);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

### [Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Use it to parse the input and handle the exception with the required message in case the parsing fails.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            try {
                n = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
                System.out.println("The number is " + n);
                // ...your business logic
            } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number: a
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a number: xyz
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a number: 4.5
The number is 4.5
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jason for the kind words.

Comment: No problem man, I just upvoted yours, definitely don't upvote mine. Great job.

Comment: @Jason - You have a heart of gold!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Arvind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62375223/4417924) for the solution.

One option would be to retrieve the input as a `String` and then use the [Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) function to ensure the input is a double. If it's not, an exception is thrown which you can handle and give the user some output.